# How to pop a tiny champagne cork?

Tags: wine

I know how to uncork champagne. However, I just got a bottle of prosecco with a tiny cork, and I'm not sure how to pop it. I can't grab it like with a normal cork, and I'm worried about putting a cork screw in there if everything is under pressure.

Here's a picture of what the cork looks like:

[image]

Comment: I was totally expecting to see a tiny bottle of champagne. If it were me (based on some Google searching), I would go with a corkscrew and some care.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [CA Wine Merchants](http://blog.cawinemerchants.com/2007/12/while-we-are-on-subject-of-prosecco.html) and [Ask Meta Filter](http://ask.metafilter.com/79004/Fumbling-for-bubbly), you simply open it with a corkscrew, as per regular wine.

Evidently, it is not so effevescent or pressurized that it needs the special cork that true champaign requires.

Comment: Good to know, I'll try that out when I'm ready to drink it. In the past I've had Prosecco with a normal cork. Thanks!